# Jenkins publishing via CFIS plugin stopped working

Tags: windows, jenkins, plugins, smb

Within a Jenkins project, there are two steps which publish artifacts to a Windows share (via the CFIS plugin for Jenkins). This worked fine, until some days ago the second post-build step stopped working; apparently nothing was changed on purpose. There is the message

```
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message
[Exception when testing config. URL [smb://somepath/],
Message: [0xC000009A]]
```

which apparently translates to "insufficient resources" based on the error code. The share itself is accessible from the machine on which Jenkins runs. 
Does anyone have an idea what the error message means in details and what could be done?

Comment: I don't know - but could it be that the file share is full or a quota has been reached (try copying a file as that user)?   Or -- If you restart Jenkins does it work "for a while" before reporting this error?  It could be the difference between IT issue vs bug in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might be considered a non-answer, rebooting the machine on which the Windows share was located resolved the issue. The problem has not occured since then.